# Sonata Propel Admin - Can't Find Service

Tags: php, symfony, propel, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I am trying to install and use the Sonata Admin Propel Package.
After basic setup it works, I can see the admin dashboard.
But when I try to define an admin service for a model I get a `The service "sonata.admin.portfolio" has a dependency on a non-existent service "sonata.admin.manager.propel"` error, which is true as I can't see it in the loaded services (`using php app/console container:debug`).

```
I installed it using composer;  
"require": {
    "propel/propel-bundle": "1.4.*",
    "sonata-project/propel-admin-bundle": "dev-master"
},
```

Registered it in AppKernel.php;

```
$bundles = array(
        new Propel\PropelBundle\PropelBundle(),
        // sonanta admin
        new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
        new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
        new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
        new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
);
```

My admin class for the model uses `Sonata\PropelAdminBundle\Admin\Admin` and is defined in admin.yml like;

```
services:
    sonata.admin.portfolio:
        class: Foo\CoreBundle\Admin\PortfolioAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: propel, group: "Content", label: "Portfolio" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - Foo\CoreBundle\Model\Portfolio
            - FooCoreBundle:PortfolioAdmin
        calls:
            - [ setTranslationDomain, [FooCoreBundle]]
```

What have I missed?

Comment: You are forgetting to enable the Sonata Propel Admin bundle in your `AppKernel.php`: `new Sonata\PropelAdminBundle\SonataPropelAdminBundle()` Let me know if this solves your problem and I'll make this comment an answer.

Comment: @sjagr congratulations for spotting the mistake!! Post that as answer - you deserve the rep for your eyes working better them mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a tiny mistake! You enabled the `PropelBundle` as necessary for the Propel ORM, but you did not enable the `SonataPropelAdminBundle` which integrates Propel with Sonata Admin.

To do so, add this line to your `AppKernel.php`:

```
new Sonata\PropelAdminBundle\SonataPropelAdminBundle(),
```

[Here are the installation instructions for Propel Admin](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/propel-admin/master/doc/reference/installation.html)